# Stuck at ".android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded."

Tags: macos, homebrew, android-sdk-2.3

```
 brew cask install android-sdk
```

> ==> Caveats We will install android-sdk-tools, platform-tools, and build-tools for you. You can control android sdk packages via the
>   sdkmanager command. You may want to add to your profile:   'export
>   ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk'
>
> This operation may take up to 10 minutes depending on your internet
>   connection. Please, be patient.
>
> ==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip
>   Already downloaded:
>   /Users/ishandutta2007/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/android-sdk--25.2.3.zip
>   ==> Verifying checksum for Cask android-sdk
>   ==> Warning: File /Users/ishandutta2007/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.

Comment: `ANDROID_HOME` is the wrong variable. The home variable should be something like `export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/.android`. It is where things like a developer's keys are stored. Based on the SDK and path, I believe they mean `export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk`

Comment: `repositories.cfg could not be loaded` warning can be ignored safely.

Answer (score 230):

Create the file! try:

```
mkdir -p .android && touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
```

Comment: Sometimes you also have to create the directory first

Comment: like what @captainserious said, I used `mkdir -p /root/.android && touch /root/.android/repositories.cfg` to make it works.

Answer (score 34):

Actually, after waiting some time it eventually goes beyond that step.
Even with `--verbose`, you won't have any information that it computes anything, but it does.

Patience is the key :)

PS : For anyone that cancelled at that step, if you try to reinstall the android-sdk package, it will complain that `Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/share/android-sdk`.
You can just `touch /usr/local/share/android-sdk` to get rid of that error and go on with the reinstall.

Answer (score 26):

This happened on Windows 10 as well. I resolved it by creating an empty  repositories.cfg file.

Comment: To anyone wondering, you can create a file easily from powershell by typing: `New-Item -Type File <filename-with-path>`

Comment: I just tried that as I have the same issue on WIn10, and when I tried running again I got a new error: "Failed to read or create install properties file"

Answer (score 14):

For Windows 7 and above go to C:\Users\USERNAME\.android folder and follow below steps:

1. Right click > create a new txt file with name repositories.txt
2. Open the file and go to File > Save As.. > select Save as type: All Files
3. Rename repositories.txt to `repositories.cfg`

Comment: or you can type "copy con repositories.cfg" and then press Ctrl+Z

Answer (score 5):

Creating a dummy blank repositories.cfg works on Windows 7 as well. After waiting for a couple of minutes the installation finishes and you get the message on your cmd window -- done

Answer (score 2):

**Windows 10 Solution:**

For me this issue was due to downloading and creating an AVD using Android Studio and then trying to use that virtual device with the Ionic command line.
I resolved this by deleting all existing emulators and creating a new one from the command line.

(the avdmanager file typically lives in C:\Users\\Android\sdk\tools\bin)

List existing emulators:
avdmanager list  avd

Delete an existing emulator:
avdmanager delete avd -n *emulator_name*

Add system image:
sdkmanager "system-images;android-24;default;x86_64"

Create new emulator:
sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on OSX Sierra, but in my case the ~/.android folder was owned by root (from a previous install) 
I changed the ownership to my User and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I used mkdir -p /root/.android && touch /root/.android/repositories.cfg to make it works