# repositories.cfg could not be loaded in Windows 10

Tags: android-studio, windows-10, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

while installing native-script i got repositories.cfg could not be loaded error , please help me debugging it. It would help me if you can give the way to download the file externally. The code i used was.....

@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"

during installation it gets stuck saying c:\user\user-name.android\repositories.cfg cannot load file

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

> Error resolved by creating an empty `repositories.cfg` file.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433542/stuck-at-android-repositories-cfg-could-not-be-loaded)

Comment: Can you share that in which directory should i create empty .cfg file? I need for windows?

Comment: @MohdSadham have you read [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43433542/6244429), anyway check the warning and add the file at desired location. ex : Warning: File /Users/vishal/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.