# How to accept licenses with flutter doctor?

Tags: android, cmd, console, flutter, android-sdk-manager

When running `flutter doctor` in the cmd it is indicated that android licenses need to be accepted by running the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

Running the command got me an error that a `repositories.cfg` could not be found at a specific directory.
I did create the empty file in the directory and waited 4~5 minutes as suggested in this SO post [repositories.cfg could not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433542/stuck-at-android-repositories-cfg-could-not-be-loaded).

Running the command again results in a new error:

> Warning: An error occurred during installation: Failed to move away or delete existing target file: `C:\installs\sdk\tools` Move it away manually and try again..

Deleting the tools folder did not solve the issue.

What do I have to do to be prompted to accept the Android licenses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to resolve the issue is to copy the `tools` folder to another place (e. g. `C:\temp`). Then navigate the cmd to the directory with `cd C:\temp\tools\bin`

```
sdkmanager.bat --sdk_root=YOUR_DIRECTORY_HERE --licenses
```

`YOUR_DIRECTORY_HERE` should be replaced with the path to your original SDK folder (`C:\installs\sdk`). Once that is done, delete the `C:\temp\tools` copied folder.

This answer was influenced by [Can't update \tools - Android SDK Command Line Tools for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43856478/6710876)