# Error setting up flutter for the first time

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am having an issue getting flutter doctor to set up or create flutter projects in Android studio.  I get the following error when I try to run flutter doctor.

> ProcessException: ProcessException: The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

Command:

```
C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.BAT --licenses
```

I already did the steps in this link:
[How to accept licenses with flutter doctor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434423/how-to-accept-licenses-with-flutter-doctor)

Comment: did u get the solution..